# how is the number of partitions used in apache spark RDD sortBy method?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am interested in the [sortBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#sortBy-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function-boolean-int-) method of apache spark.

Here is an example that is used in one of the projects I am looking at. 
I am not clear what sorting is happening here. Looking at the spark documentation isn't clear either. How is the number of partitions used this sorting method?

```
public void doSorting(JavaDStream<Foo> stream, int num) {

return stream.map(foo -> foo.getKey().sortBy(key -> key, true, num).collect())

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sortBy` use `RangePartitioner` to shuffle the data. `numPartitions` determines number of partitions used by the `Partitioner` (number of partitions used by the output `RDD`).

Comment: Is the data shuffled across all partitions during sorting?